# Trouble parsing dataset to date format

Tags: r, lubridate

I am currently converting 3 different datasets to date format before I attempt to merge them. The first two I had no problem using `lubridate` to parse the date column

```
COVID19$Date <- lubridate::ymd(COVID19$Date)
TESTS$Date <- lubridate::ymd(TESTS$Date)
```

However with the third data set when I use the same `lubridate` function I receive the following warning

```
RECOVERED_tidy <- lubridate::ymd(RECOVERED_tidy$Date)
Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

This dataset was previously tidied so all the date columns were merged into one column using:

```
RECOVERED_tidy <- pivot_longer(RECOVERED, starts_with("X"), names_to = "date", values_to = "recovered")
```

Is this why it won't use the same function?

Thanks for any help!

EDIT:

Sample of Recovered data

```
 Country     Date        Recovered
  <fct>       <chr>           <int>
1 Afghanistan X2020.01.22         0
2 Afghanistan X2020.01.23         0
3 Afghanistan X2020.01.24         0
4 Afghanistan X2020.01.25         0
5 Afghanistan X2020.01.26         0
6 Afghanistan X2020.01.27         0
```

Comment: @Dave2e will the edit made to the original post suffice?

Comment: @RonakShah will the edit made to the original post suffice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the additional `'X'` present in the data, you can do that with `sub`.

```
RECOVERED_tidy$Date <- lubridate::ymd(sub('X', '', RECOVERED_tidy$Date))
```

You can also use `as.Date` in base R :

```
RECOVERED_tidy$Date <- as.Date(RECOVERED_tidy$Date, 'X%Y.%m.%d')
```

Comment: That removes my other variables though?

Comment: @Jaz You need to update only the column. See updated answer.